# could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

When I try to run `rails console` / `rails server` / `rake db:create` , it shows this message :

> Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources

and my order does not execute, why I am getting message like this?

Thanks master

This is my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem "byebug"
gem "pg"
gem "barby"
gem "devise"
gem "rails_12factor", group: :production
gem "chunky_png"
gem 'cloudinary'

gem "grape"
gem "hashie_rails"
gem 'grape-rails-routes'

gem 'zxing'
```

========================

My Gemfile.lock :

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
      actionmailer (4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      actionpack (4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      actionview (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      activemodel (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      activerecord (4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
      activesupport (4.1.6)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
      aws_cf_signer (0.1.3)
      axiom-types (0.1.1)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.4)
      ice_nine (~> 0.11.0)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
      barby (0.6.2)
      bcrypt (3.1.10)
      builder (3.2.2)
      byebug (5.0.0)
      columnize (= 0.9.0)
      chunky_png (1.3.4)
      cloudinary (1.1.0)
      aws_cf_signer
      rest-client
      coercible (1.0.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
      coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
      coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
      columnize (0.9.0)
      descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
      devise (3.5.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
      domain_name (0.5.24)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
      equalizer (0.0.11)
      erubis (2.7.0)
      execjs (2.5.2)
      grape (0.11.0)
      activesupport
      builder
      hashie (>= 2.1.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.3.2)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
      rack (>= 1.3.0)
      rack-accept
      rack-mount
      virtus (>= 1.0.0)
      grape-rails-routes (1.0)
      rails (>= 4.1.4)
      hashie (3.4.2)
      hashie_rails (0.0.4)
      hashie (>= 3.0)
      hike (1.2.3)
      http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
      i18n (0.7.0)
      ice_nine (0.11.1)
      jbuilder (2.2.16)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
      jquery-rails (3.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
      jruby-jars (1.7.20)
      json (1.8.3)
      mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
      mime-types (2.6.1)
      minitest (5.7.0)
      multi_json (1.11.0)
      multi_xml (0.5.5)
      netrc (0.10.3)
      orm_adapter (0.5.0)
      pg (0.18.2)
      rack (1.5.3)
      rack-accept (0.4.5)
      rack (>= 0.4)
      rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
      rails (4.1.6)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activerecord (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.6)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
      rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
      rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
      rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
      railties (4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
      rake (10.4.2)
      rdoc (4.2.0)
      responders (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
      rest-client (1.8.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
      netrc (~> 0.7)
      sass (3.2.19)
      sass-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
      sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
      spring (1.3.6)
      sprockets (2.12.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
      sprockets-rails (2.3.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      thor (0.19.1)
      thread_safe (0.3.5)
      tilt (1.4.1)
      turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
      tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      uglifier (2.7.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
      unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
      unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
      virtus (1.0.5)
      axiom-types (~> 0.1)
      coercible (~> 1.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.3)
      equalizer (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.9)
      warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
      zxing (0.4.0)
      jruby-jars

PLATFORMS
  java
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  barby
  byebug
  chunky_png
  cloudinary
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  devise
  grape
  grape-rails-routes
  hashie_rails
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 4.1.6)
  rails_12factor
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  zxing
```

Any solution??

Comment: do you have `source 'https://rubygems.org'` in your gemfile and did you run `bundle` in your project directory?  post your gemfile and gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your terminal

```
gem 'rake', '10.4.2'
```

and then

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```